# SFrame from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, sframe

I would like to create an [`SFrame`](https://github.com/turi-code/SFrame) from a `NumPy` array.

What i want specifically is:

```
np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
```

=>

```
+----+----+----+----+
| 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
+----+----+----+----+
| 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
| 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  |
| 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 |
| 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
+----+----+----+----+
[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

If I do:

```
print SFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4))
```

I get:

```
+--------------------------+
|            X1            |
+--------------------------+
|   [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]   |
|   [4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]   |
|  [8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0]  |
| [12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0] |
+--------------------------+
[4 rows x 1 columns]
```

I can get what I want if I convert the `NumPy` array to a `Pandas` `DataFrame` and from the `Pandas` `DataFrame` to an `SFrame`:

```
print SFrame(pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)))

+----+----+----+----+
| 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
+----+----+----+----+
| 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
| 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  |
| 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 |
| 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
+----+----+----+----+
[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

My question is:

How can I create an `SFame` from a `NumPy` array in the way that a `Pandas` `DataFrame` reads it (array `NxM` => `DataFrame` with `N` rows and `M` columns), but without using `Pandas` as an intermediate step?

Comment: I can't confirm but SFrame takes a dictionary.  Try: `{str(i): np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4).T[i] for i in range(4)}`

Comment: if SFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)) works, try  SFrame(pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)).values) .values will return the properly shaped np.array

Comment: I want to return SFrame from numpy array. It works if I do:

numpy => pandas DataFrame => SFrame

But I would love to exclude intermediate step and have:
numpy => SFrame

Answer (score 1):

I also has this issue, I also find multi-indexing hard in SFrame.

may be silly fix but still workable;

```
from graphlab import SFrame,SArray

data=np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4).T 
sf=SFrame(map(SArray,data)
```

should result in something like this

```
X1  X2  X3  X4
0   1   2   3
4   5   6   7
8   9   10  11
12  13  14  15
```